# Special relativity: how to prove that $g = L^t g L$?

Tags: special-relativity, linear-algebra

We have 
$$X^\textrm{t}gX = 0 \iff X^\textrm{t}L^\textrm{t}gLX = 0,$$ 
where $X$ is a column vector of length four, $L$ is a non-singular $4 \times 4$ matrix, 't' denotes matrix transpose, and 
$$g = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{matrix}\right)\,.$$ 
doesn't it immediately follow that $g = L^\textrm{t}gL,$ since $$X^\textrm{t}gX = 0 \iff X^\textrm{t}\left(L^\textrm{t}gL\right)X = 0?$$ 
Why or why not? I ask because the proof in my book takes up an entire page, so I have a feeling that this argument is not sound.

It shouldn't matter for the question, but $X$ and $L$ come from the following equations:
$$X = \left(\begin{matrix}
ct_2 \\ x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2
\end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}
ct_1 \\ x_1 \\ y_z \\ z_1
\end{matrix}\right)\,,$$ where $t_1$, $x_1$, $y_1$, $z_1$ and $t_2$, $x_2$, $y_2$, $z_2$ are the inertial coordinates of two events, and 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
ct \\ x \\ y \\ z
\end{matrix}\right) = L \,\left(\begin{matrix}
ct^\prime \\ x^\prime \\ y^\prime \\ z^\prime
\end{matrix}\right) + C,$$ which gives the Lorentz transformation from the primed to the unprimed inertial coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask

> doesn't it immediately follow that $g=L^tgL$ ?

Nope.

Consider, for example, $L = aI$ where a is a nonzero real number, and $I$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix.  This matrix $L$ is nonsingular, and it has the property that 
\begin{align}
  X^tgX = 0\,\quad\text{if and only if}\quad X^tL^tgLX = 0
\end{align}
for all $X\in \mathbb R^4$, but notice that
\begin{align}
  L^t gL = a^2 g\neq g.
\end{align}

**Intuition.** By the way, you might be wondering how I came up with such a slick counterexample (if I may indulge in a bit of self-flattery).  Well it came from some physical intuition.  Note that the condition $X^tgX = 0$ simply says that $X$ is a null vector, so if $X^tgX = 0$ if and only if $X^tL^tgLX = 0$, then this just means that $g$ and $L^tgL$ agree in their action in the light cone.  Then I thought, "oh, but the light cone is scale invariant, so metrics related by scaling can still agree on the light cone."  Voila.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it would only follow if $X^\textrm{t}gX = X^\textrm{t}L^\textrm{t}gLX$.

Comment: @fctaylor25 Yes, provided there is an implicit universal quantifier "for all $X$" there (or some sufficiently large class of $X$ at least).  I also added a section on intuition.

Comment: I'm glad you added the section on intuition. I was wondering how you thought of that.

Comment: @fctaylor25 I'm glad you're glad.  Happy to help.